# Coin flipping limit

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, binomial-distribution, probability-limit-theorems

Let $S_{n}\sim\text{Bin}\left(n,p\left(n\right)\right)$ where $p\left(n\right)$
is the unique solution to the equation $\delta\left(p\left(n\right),n\right)=0$
with $\delta$ being continuous and bounded, strictly decreasing in
$p$ with $\delta\left(0,n\right)>0$ and $\delta\left(1,n\right)<0$
for all $n\geq2$. We also have that $p\left(n\right)$ is strictly decreasing in $n$.

How to justify rigorously that there exists a unique
(fixed) $p$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(E\left[S_{n}\right]-n\cdot p\right)=0$,
where $p$ is the unique solution to the equation $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\delta\left(p\left(n\right),n\right)=0$?

Comment: My guess is that we need a non-iid version of CLT and that the question is related to this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2416665/law-of-large-numbers-for-non-identically-distributed-bernoulli-random-variables). Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true without additional assumptions. Here is a counterexample.

For fixed $n$, Let $\delta(x,n)$ be the linear interpotation between $1$ and $0$ between $x=0$ and $x=\frac 12 + \frac 1n$, and the linear interpolation between $0$ and $-1$ between $x=\frac 12 + \frac 1n$ and $x=1$.

Then $\delta$ satisfies all the requirements and $p(n) = \frac 12 + \frac 1n$ is decreasing to $p=\frac 12$.

However,

$$E[S_n] - np = n (\frac 12 + \frac 1n) - n \frac 12 =1.$$

Comment: +1, thank you so much. But looking at your answer and [Example 14.5 in these notes](http://personal.psu.edu/drh20/asymp/fall2002/lectures/ln04.pdf) made me more confused now. The only assumption that this Example requires is that the limit $p_n  (1-p_n)$ to be non-zero. Why can't I use it?

Comment: If it helps, the $\delta$ function I am referring to is stated in [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3151593/series-limit-involving-binomial-coefficients).

Comment: I see now what I misunderstood. The non-iid version of CLT applies in my setting and implies specifically that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(E\left[S_{n}\right]-n\cdot p\left(n\right)\right)=0$. To show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(E\left[S_{n}\right]-n\cdot p\right)=0$ indeed needs more information.